# AWS S3 bucket , uploaded image files are accessible only after setting individual object permission to public manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a bucket & after image uploaded from my website development server it store as XML file,  If I go to bucket and make it public manually it becomes available to all and I am able to get that file.

What might be the problem here ?

setting each uploaded file to public as below
[image]

I set `access= objects can be public`

```
Block all public access = False
```

CORS CONFIGURATION

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

INITIAL ERROR WHEN TRYING TO ACCESS THE UPLOADED IMAGE

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>XX</RequestId>
<HostId>XXZjXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I go to bucket and make it public manually it becomes available to all and I am able to get that file. What might be the problem here ?

You don't have to do it manually. Instead, to **automatically** make all objects in your bucket publicly readable , a **bucket policy** can be added:

- [Granting Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)

For example:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket-name>/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You will also need to **keep** `block public access settings` disabled.

Comment: Thank you, where should I paste the above code ? Is that in bucket policy ?

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge Its in Bucket's `Permissions` tab under `Bucket Policy`.

Answer (score 1):

The setting itself is to allow them the ability to be public.

If you want all objects (or those with a specific prefix) then take a look at create a S3 bucket policy that allows the `S3:GetObject` permission.

An example of this bucket policy is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2).